Add AWS Cognito authentication to a Blazor WebAssembly standalone app
I cannot find a step by step guide for using AWS Cognito in a Blazor WebAssembly standalone app for net 8
Microsoft did  produce a guide but not for Cognito.
I did find a very good guide for adding Cognito but to a Blazor web app which does require a server.
